# Selenium Webdriver Mouse

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to build a mouse for Firefox Webdriver in Ruby: no success so far.

```
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
@mouse = Selenium::WebDriver::Mouse.new(@driver)
@mouse.click(@driver.find_element :css => 'li:nth-child(1)')
```

Traceback of the mistake

```
test_add_course(ItemAutocompleteTest): 
NoMethodError: undefined method 
mouseMoveTo for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x7fa66e372b18 browser=:firefox>
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:50:in move_to
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:60:in move_if_needed
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-0.2.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:12:in click
test/selenium_2/item_autocomplete_test.rb:36:in test_add_course
mocha (0.9.8) lib/mocha/integration/test_unit/ruby_version_186_and_above.rb:19:in __send__
mocha (0.9.8) lib/mocha/integration/test_unit/ruby_version_186_and_above.rb:19:in run

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors
```

Here I found the similar problem
https://gist.github.com/967333

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Why are you doing this?  The standard .click command uses the mouse implementation anyway as does the Actions implementation (although i'm not sure Actions has been implemented in ruby).  The Mouse implementation isn't really designed for external usage.

Comment: I just wanted to profit from what webdriver has to offer - advanced user interactions. Let's say i needed to double click the item. The problem is why the mouse doesn't initialize? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll notice the [Mouse class](http://rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/2.2.0/Selenium/WebDriver/Mouse) is marked as private in the docs - it's not part of the public API. To use the advanced user interactions, you want to look at the [ActionBuilder](http://rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/2.2.0/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder) instead, basically:

```
driver.action.key_down(:shift).
              click(element).
              double_click(second_element).
              key_up(:shift).
              drag_and_drop(element, third_element).
              perform
```

I'll add a section about this to the [wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings).

Comment: Does selenium have the ability to click at certain mouse coordinates? I need to trigger an automated click, but I need to do it outside of the browser environment. It's a very unusual case.

Comment: It doesn't support clicking outside the browser (at the moment), no.

Comment: You can click outside the browser using Sikuli library.